# Grant full access to files on Windows Server 2008, only for a limited amount of time

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2008, powershell

I have a local Windows network with a Windows Server 2008 whose purpose is to act as a file server. I'm the administrator.

I want to grant user full access to all the files on a certain directory i.e. `D:\`. This "super power" period should only last for a day and then return to the original permission status.

How can I do this with PowerShell (or the old VBScript)? Or what would a Windows administrator typically do (with scripting and not GUI)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Set-ACL cmdlet to grant the permissions, then schedule a task that runs a different script using Set-ACL to remove the permissions.

I would also use Get-ACL and export the current ACL to somewhere so it's easier to roll back.

I've used it before but can't find the script, however you can set inherit permissions and so forth also.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849810.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176838.aspx